# How do I replace every word with one word?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I would like Javascript which changes all text on a page to a specific string. For example, if I wanted to set every word to 'Hello':

Before:

```
Hey there, how are you?
```

After:

```
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

How would this be done? It would do it to the entire page, so it would need to leave HTML tags as they were and just change the text contents.

This code must be executed **after** the page has loaded.

Comment: is the page layout supposed to stay the same after? if you replace html tags, it will all be a jumbled mess...

Comment: I suppose that he refers to the innerHTML, but I also suppose that he want to hack some page haha

Comment: You can take a look at how XKCD Substitutions does it.   https://github.com/Posnet/xkcd-substitutions

Comment: Yes, the page layout needs to be the exact same as it was before. I just want the text to be different.

Comment: Sound like a regex job :)

Comment: Probably this is a good read before you do anything: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function malkovich(node) {
  if(node.nodeType === 1)
    return [].forEach.call(node.childNodes, malkovich);
  if(node.nodeType === 3)  
    node.textContent = node.textContent
         .replace(/\b[A-Z]\w+/g, "Malkovich")
         .replace(/\b[a-z]\w+/g, "malkovich")
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi, there!</h1>
<p>Some <b>more</b> text...</p>
<p>"Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum <u>unam</u> incolunt <i>Belgae</i>, <u>aliam</u> <i>Aquitani</i>, <u>tertiam</u> qui ipsorum lingua <i>Celtae</i>, nostra <i>Galli</i> appellantur". </p>
<button onclick="malkovich(document.body)">malkovich</button>
```

Comment: nice "hello world"! such a great flick...

Comment: @dandavis: yeah, absolutely love it...

Comment: It works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turn everything into a string, then use the `.replace` method

```
"Hey there, how are you?".replace(/[^\s]+/g, "Hello");
// replaces any non-space sequence with over 1 character

// outputs "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello"
```

I would highly recommend https://regex101.com/

You can also match characters `[a-zA-Z]+` positively, just mess around with it

Good luck

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem of not destructing the page layout...